# Finding normal probabilities (battery life)

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

The lifespan of a calculator battery is normally distributed with a mean of 1100 days & standard dev. of 60 days. $$\\$$

1) What percent of batteries is expected to survive more than 1200 days?

2) What percent of batteries will survive fewer than 800 days?

3) What length of warranty is needed so that no more than 10% of the batteries will be expected to fail during the warranty period? $$\\$$

This is what I have so far:

1) $P(x > 1200)$

= $1-P(\frac{1200-1100}{60})$

= $1-P(1.67)$

= $1-0.9525$

= **0.0475**

2) $P(x < 800)$

= $P(\frac{800-1100}{60})$

= $P(-5)$

= **0**

I'm not sure how to do #3.

I would appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Think about question 1, imagine 1200 was unknown, and suppose the 0.0475 was given to you. How would you recover 1200?

Comment: @Just_to_Answer This is what I was thinking:$\frac{x-1100}{60}$ = -1.28, x= 1023.2 days. But I'm not sure if that's right

Comment: Pretty much the right idea, but if you looked carefully through your solution in question 1, you should see this: 0.0475 is a probability smaller than 1/2 which corresponds to the "1.67" being positive. So the "-1.28" doesnt do what you want it to do.

Comment: In other words, 0.0475 is on the right tail in problem 1. You want `no more than 10% of the batteries will be expected to fail` - i.e., you want 0.10 on the right tail.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer so i would set $\frac{x-1100}{60}$ = 0.10 or 1.28 ??

Comment: Yes. If a better accuracy is needed, `1.28` should be replaced with `1.281552` Please go ahead and provide an answer to your own question so that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: Approximating something where negative values are meaningless with a normally distributed random variable is a moral crime.

Comment: I think a couple of comments are in the wrong tail. // @MattSamuel.  Not relevant here, but sometimes done to useful effect when the probability of negative values is negligible. Of course, there are no 'moral crimes' in abstract algebra.

Comment: AmR: My apologies that you were correct on your original attempt with -1.28. I should have thought about it for a minute before confusing you. And thanks @BruceET for looking at it carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I can be of the most help by encouraging you to use notation
that makes sense.  Your write:

$$P(x > 1200) = 1-P\left(\frac{1200-1100}{60}\right) = 1-P(1.67) = 1-0.9525 = 0.0475,$$

in which the second and third terms contain no events and so make no sense.

I suggest something like this: You have 
$X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 1100,\, \sigma=60)$ and seek
$P(X > 1200).$ Then
$$P(X > 1200) = 1 - P(X \le 1200) = 
1-P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{1200 - 1100}{60}\right)\\
= 1 - P(Z \le 1.67) = 1 -  0.9525 = 0.0475,$$
where the approximate numerical answer can be obtained from printed tables of the standard
normal CDF.

You can get a slightly more accurate answer using software without having to standardize. For
example in R statistical software. The improved accuracy is because rounding
is avoided. (In R, `pnorm` is the CDF of the normal distribution with mean
and SD given in the second and third arguments.)

```
1 - pnorm(1200, 1100, 60)
## 0.04779035
```

---

Then in the last part, you seek $w$ such that $P(X \le w) = 0.10.$ So write
$$P(X \le w) = P\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{w-1100}{60}\right)
= P(Z \le (w-1100)/60) = 0.10,$$
Then by normal tables $(w-1100)/60 \approx -1.28,$ and you can solve for $w.$

A slightly more accurate answer can be obtained by software:

```
 qnorm(.1, 1100, 60)   # 'qnorm' is the inverse CDF or 'quantile' function
 ## 1023.107
 pnorm(1023, 1100, 60) # as a check
 ## 0.09968766
```

Notice (as some Commenters did not) that the company offering the warranty is stingy, not
wanting to pay out for more than 10% of purchases.

---

Also, it usually helps to make sketches. Here is a graph of the density
function of $\mathsf{Norm}(1100, 60),$ with vertical red lines marking
locations of interest in the parts above.

[image]

Of course, you can't sketch with such good accuracy just by hand, but with
a little effort you can learn to make a facsimile of a normal
density curve that is a lot better than no sketch at all.